# Maven site:deploy error: "Error uploading site: Error performing commands for file transfer: Exit code: 0 - The syntax of the command is incorrect."

Tags: java, maven, maven-site-plugin

I'm attempting to use the site:deploy feature of Maven to deploy a project site to a server on my local network. The server is running Windows Server 2012.

I have successfully set up an Apache Archiva Maven repository on it, and I am able to deploy my projects and pull dependencies to/from it just fine.

When I run `mvn site:deploy`, I get this:

```
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.6:deploy (default-deploy) @ piserver ---
[INFO] Pushing C:\Users\Eric\Development\Projects\Java\PiServerJava\target\site
[INFO]    >>> to scp://192.168.1.215/inetpub/wwwroot/software/projects/piserver/./
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.631 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-30T10:11:55-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/219M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-
plugin:3.6:deploy (default-deploy) on project piserver: Error uploading
site: Error performing commands for file transfer: Exit code: 0 - The syntax
of the command is incorrect.
```

My POM `<distributionManagement>` section looks like this:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <site>
        <id>etv-site</id>
        <url>scp://192.168.1.215/inetpub/wwwroot/software/projects/piserver/</url>
    </site>
</distributionManagement>
```

and my settings.xml `<server>` section looks like this:

```
<server>
    <id>etv-site</id>
    <username>********</username>
    <password>********</password>
</server>
```

For my wagon provider, I use

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

No matter what I try for a url in `<distributionManagement>`, I get the same error. I've tried

- `scp://192.168.1.215/inetpub/wwwroot/software/projects/piserver/`
- `scp://192.168.1.215/C:/inetpub/wwwroot/software/projects/piserver/`
- `scp://192.168.1.215/software/projects/piserver/`

among others.

Other things I've tried:

- URL: `scp:http://192.168.1.215/inetpub/wwwroot/software/projects/piserver/`; Error: `Cannot connect. Reason: java.net.UnknownHostException`.
- URL: `sftp://192.168.1.215/inetpub/wwwroot/software/projects/piserver/`; Error: `Error uploading site: Exit code: 0 - 'chmod' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  [ERROR] operable program or batch file.`

For reference, my Archiva repository URLs look like this:

```
<repository>
    <id>etv-internal</id>
    <url>http://192.168.1.215:8080/repository/internal</url>
</repository>
<snapshotRepository>
    <id>etv-snapshots</id>
    <url>http://192.168.1.215:8080/repository/snapshots</url>
</snapshotRepository>
```

---

### UPDATE:

The `sftp://` solution successfully deploys my site, but I still get the chmod error. I would still like to use scp instead of sftp, though.

Comment: You shall execute the command
`mvn site:deploy`
to deploy the package using site-plugin

Comment: That is what I am doing.

Comment: If you don't want to use `chmod` you can flag it false

Comment: How? @nullpointer

Comment: include in the site plugin configuration `<chmod>false</chmod>`

Comment: and anyway the ideal solution to the problem shall be a connection linked(access across) between the host where you are deploying and from where you are trying to deploy.

Comment: does that solve your problem?

Comment: You're not being clear enough. I am not sure how to set chmod to false. I'm reading this: [https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-site-plugin/deploy-mojo.html](https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-site-plugin/deploy-mojo.html). I'm assuming I put `<chmod>false</chmod>` in a `<configurations>` block, but do I put that in `<executions>` or just under `<artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>`?

Comment: have updated the same in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Undeleting the answer and keeping the state of what was edited in the question. You shall execute the command

```
mvn site:deploy
```

to deploy the package using [site-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/deploy-mojo.html)

In order to set the `chmod` to false for the site deployment you can use the following configurations :

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
      <chmod>false</chmod>
   </configuration>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
         <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
         <version>2.10</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

This would not require changing the `execution` phase for your plugin either.

Comment: I correct myself. Using this solution does eliminate the chmod error. Thanks for this! I would still like it to work with scp, though.